# How to pronounce the word fission?

Tags: pronunciation, listening

sometimes I hear the word "Fission" as "Fi**sh**on" and sometimes I hear it as "Fi**j**on".
What is the correct american pronunciation? do you pronounce the "ss" as "**j**" or "**sh**" ?

Also, What about the word "fusion"?

Comment: What is your native language?  I ask, because the "ss" sound in "fission" sounds nothing like a "j" sound in American English, but it might in your native language.

Comment: Most of the better online dictionaries include sound clips of conventional pronunciations, e.g. [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/fission), [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/fission), and [AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=fission) to start.

Comment: The **ss** in **fission** is like **mission**, not like mi**ss**ile. I guess it could be similar to **j** in **je**("I" in French)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really a mix between "sh" and "j." The closest character that I can think of that matches the sound would be the Russian "ж" character, but that's a bit too harsh.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3H-3LhSAoA) provides correct pronunciation of the word.

It is the same sound that we use in these words:

- leisure
- fusion
- lesion

Note: It looks like this does depend on region of the country!

Comment: The sound is usually written phonetically as 'zh', because it is the voiced counterpart to 'sh', just as 'z' is the voiced counterpart to 's'.

Comment: There is a clear difference in my neck of the woods between the /sh/ of "mission" and "fission" (identical to the /sh/ of initial-sh words like "shoot" and "shelter") and the /zh/ of "fusion", "leisure", etc.

Comment: @Hellion really? Interesting. I've always heard it pronounced as /zh/. It looks like this may have a lot to do with region!

Comment: @AlexK Apparently so. :-) My "neck of the woods" is Minnesota, previously Maryland, and I don't recall hearing /zh/ in "mission" in either area.

Comment: @Hellion My "neck(s) of the woods" is/are New York, Kentucky, and California. I also haven't ever heard /zh/ in "mission," but in school, was taught /zh/ in "fission"

Comment: @AlexK okay, I should have said "I never heard a /zh/ in 'fission' in either area".  :-)  "Fission" and "Mission" are identical except for the initial consonant in my parts.

Comment: New York City native here: I'm with Hellion.  Here, "fission" is "fish-un", not "fizh-un".